Looking for Help to Upgrade from Magento 1.9.4.0 to Magento M2E Pro
We have an ecommerce website built on Magento 1.9.4.0 (www.dieselcranks.com) and we have built an integration so orders from Magento come into our ERP software Microsoft AX. I am looking to move from 1.9.4.0 to the most current Magento or Adobe Commerce or whatever it's called, but neither myself nor anyone on my team as the know-how to do this so I'm looking for a reputable person to do this for us and I want to find out if our AX integration will still work after the migration.
Any help would be appreciated as our webstore is quite old and very much in need of an update. Thanks.

We use M2E Pro with Magento 2.4.6.p4, moving to Magento 2.4.7.  You should contact the M2E Pro support team, they are very good at helping with whatever we need. I expect they will do the same for you.
Have a blessed week,
Richard Wendrock
